# How do i insert different fields from one table to another in mysql,vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
INSERT INTO invoice
SELECT invoiceid, customerid
FROM accountinginvoice where invoiceid='0380'
```

I tried this but, error occurred as

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Please help me. I have so many different columns and bulk data in both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Here we got 2 tables, Table1 and Table2.
we are selecting Table1.userName and Table2.Userid into a new BackupData Table.
The folloiwing is a straight forward query and i hope this helps.
*/

SELECT Table1.UserName, Table2.UserID
INTO BackupData
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.UserID=Table2.UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

while using an insert query you are required to provide the columns to which the values are to be inserted.an insert statement using select query will look like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

where this query executes to insert value into the column fld_id of tbl_temp2.

for more examples http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html